# How can I return a name from an array of names instead of a number?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return the name of the oldest person in an array. My function is working in the sense that it returns the oldest person's age in the form of a number, however I can't figure out how to return the name of the person instead. Just a hint in the right direction would be appreciated.

```js
    const people = [
      {
        name: "Carly",
        yearOfBirth: 1066,
      },
      {
        name: "Ray",
        yearOfBirth: 1962,
        yearOfDeath: 2011,
      },
      {
        name: "Jane",
        yearOfBirth: 1912,
        yearOfDeath: 1941,
      },
    ]


const findTheOldest = function() {
  let age = people.map(function(person) {
    const birth = person.yearOfBirth;
    let death = person.yearOfDeath;
    if (!person.yearOfDeath) {
      death = new Date().getFullYear();
    }
     return death - birth;
  });
  const oldest = age.sort((a, b) => a > b ? 1 : -1);
  return oldest[oldest.length-1];
};

findTheOldest();
```

Comment: so, you have two options. go back to the array and find names that match the age (there could be multiple,) or rewrite your logic such that it actually does what you want it to do, rather than just finding the largest number. Start by not using map.

Comment: Use `Array.sort` and work with object.

Comment: you can use Array.reduce. it is more efficient than sort. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to get the person with the highest age, then get the first element's `name` property:

```js
const people = [{
    name: "Carly",
    yearOfBirth: 1066,
  },
  {
    name: "Ray",
    yearOfBirth: 1962,
    yearOfDeath: 2011,
  },
  {
    name: "Jane",
    yearOfBirth: 1912,
    yearOfDeath: 1941,
  },
]


const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear()
const findTheOldest = function() {
  return people.sort((a, b) => (a.yearOfDeath - (b.yearOfBirth || currentYear)) - (b.yearOfDeath - (b.yearOfBirth || currentYear)))[0].name
};

console.log(findTheOldest())
```

Comment: Hardcoded the years at `2021` will not help if we change years. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can `sort` without mapping, calculating the age in the sort callback.

```js
const people = [{
    name: "Carly",
    yearOfBirth: 1066,
  },
  {
    name: "Ray",
    yearOfBirth: 1962,
    yearOfDeath: 2011,
  },
  {
    name: "Jane",
    yearOfBirth: 1912,
    yearOfDeath: 1941,
  },
]


const findTheOldest = function() {
  const getAge = p => (p.yearOfDeath || new Date().getFullYear()) - p.yearOfBirth;
  return [...people].sort((a, b)=>getAge(b) - getAge(a))[0].name;
};

console.log(findTheOldest());
```

Note, however, that the oldest person can be found more efficiently with a single loop (e.g. with `Array#reduce`), without sorting.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code helping you

```
//get array of ages
var agearray = people.map(o=>o.yearOfDeath ==undefined? new Date().getFullYear()-o.yearOfBirth:o.yearOfDeath-o.yearOfBirth)
//get name of old person

var oldperson = people[agearray.indexOf(Math.max(...agearray))].name
console.log(oldperson)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to find the result.

```js
const people = [
      {
        name: "Carly",
        yearOfBirth: 1066,
      },
      {
        name: "Ray",
        yearOfBirth: 1962,
        yearOfDeath: 2011,
      },
      {
        name: "Jane",
        yearOfBirth: 1912,
        yearOfDeath: 1941,
      },
    ]
const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
const result = people.reduce((prev,cur) => {
      return (prev.yearOfDeath || currentYear) - prev.yearOfBirth < (cur.yearOfDeath || currentYear) - cur.yearOfBirth ? cur: prev;
    });
    
console.log('name:', result.name);
console.log('age: ', (result.yearOfDeath || currentYear) - result.yearOfBirth);
```